# How to give super user privileges for the existing user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

How to create super user for the existing user in postgresql, i want to give the super user permission for the abc user, now this user has only create DB rights only, i want give as super user anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alteruser.html):

```
ALTER USER the_user SUPERUSER;
```